# CiviRules and deprecated CRM_Core_OptionGroup::getValue

Tags: civirules

Using CiviRules 2.14.1 to process inbound SMS messages. It is driving the warning below in the log. This [2.0 blog](https://civicrm.org/blog/erikhommel/civirules-release-20-is-available) refers to removing calls to deprecated CRM_Core_OptionGroup::getLabel, but I can't find mention of getValue. Not looking for an answer so much as making sure this is a known behavior. If it's just me, I need to worry!

> May 07 11:13:00  [warning] Deprecated function CRM_Core_OptionGroup::getValue, use CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::getKey.
>
> Array 
>   (
>      [civi.tag] => deprecated
>   )
>
> May 07 11:13:00  [info] Inbound SMS recorded for cid=1320.